# CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed

Tags: gradle, build, ads, failover

Can someone help me with this Error?

- I put ADS in my project, and I'm getting this error when I try to build my project to Android.
- But if I put ADS OFFLINE, then the error disappears.

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
>   C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe -classpath "E:\unity 5\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradleOut'.

  > Cannot add task ':prepareUnityAdsLibrary' as a task with that name already exists.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> BUILD FAILED in 2s
>
> NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
>   If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to D:\AndroidUnityGames\SDKROOTandroiddevelopern\ndk-bundle.
>   If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.
>
> NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
>   If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to D:\AndroidUnityGames\SDKROOTandroiddevelopern\ndk-bundle.
>   If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.
>
> The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
>   The getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method instead.
>   The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead.
>
> exit code: 1
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
>   UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
>   Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
>   UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: please follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

- Build system can be 'Internal' or 'Gradle'.
- Selecting 'Internal' can eliminate the problem but according to new Google Play Store policies, game must be 32-bit (ARMv7) and 64-bit (ARM64) compatible (i.e. IL2CPP Scripting Backend).
- For that 'Gradle' build is necessary. Older versions of UNITY have this kind of problem, to overcome it, you have to download a stable one (e.g. UNITY 2018.4.9f1). Now in the 'preferences', check in the box for 'Stop gradle daemons on exit'.
- This cures our problem for 'gradle' build and provides us with .aab and .zip ext files. This .aab file is to be uploaded instead of .apk to the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

It works switching from Gradle to Internal:

[image]